# PHP strings to automatically downloaded zip

Tags: php, string, forms, download, zip

I have a php file which reads data from an user submitted form and puts it into two different  strings. I want to put these strings in separate txt files and put them into a zip archive which would be downloaded by the user when he submits the form.

How can I do that? And is there a way to give each zip an unique name so there wouldn't be any possible conflicts?

Comment: Check out the ziparchive class. http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php You could use fwrite to write to the text files, then ziparchive to archive it afterwords. Then you can pass it to a content disposition header to download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two text files with fwrite and then use the `create_zip` function described here http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php like this:

```
$files_to_zip = array(
'textFileA.txt',
'textFileB.txt'
);
$zip_name = uniqid().'.zip';
$result = create_zip($files_to_zip, $zip_name);
```

And then use a HTTP header to download the ZIP file created.